# How to test Spark GraphX new example SSSPExample.scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

A new Graphx example is posted on Apache's git hub repository at https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/graphx/SSSPExample.scala.

The code includes a line: bin/run-example graphx.SSSPExample

I've tried run-example as above, but did not work. I think that I need to build a JAR firstly. I do not have experience with sbt. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

In general all example can be executed with pre-built binaries by using `bin/run-examples` and passing class name. `SSSPExample` is relatively new addition though (it has been merged a few days ago) so you'll have to use [nightly builds](https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-bin/latest/) or [build Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html) from [source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0bd7cd18bc4d535b0c4499913f6747b3f6315ac2/docs/graphx-programming-guide.md).

After that just go to `SPARK_HOME` and execute:

```
bin/run-example graphx.SSSPExample
```

Alternatively just adjust this code according to the version of Spark you use and [build](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications) or execute in [interactive shell](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#interactive-analysis-with-the-spark-shell).

Comment: Thanks for answering, it's a good suggestion.  To  avoid building Spark ( or downloading a new bin files) I wonder how can I incorporate this new source code SSSPExample to  lib/spark-examples-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar.

Comment: a) It is not even remotely that simple. b) This code is not 1.6 compatible anyway.